# Java NIO questions on multithreading

Tags: java, io, nio

With Java Nio can you :

1.) Use an asyncrhonousFileChannel with a selector?

2.) Create multiple channels to a single file?

If I were to open multiple RandomAccesFiles to the same empty file, would I be able to write to various locations given that I knew how much bytes are going to be written per line, and the maximum number of lines?

Comment: 1. The idea of using any kind of an asynchronous channel with a `Selector` is a contradiction in terms. 2. You don't need multiple channels or multiple `RandomAccessFiles` to accompish that objective.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) Use an asyncrhonousFileChannel with a selector?

`Selector` only support `SelectableChannel` and the `SelectableChannel` must work in no-blocking mode,`AsynchronousFileChannel` use thread pool and callback to do async work,so `AsynchronousFileChannel` can't work with a Selector.

> 2.) Create multiple channels to a single file?

Yes,you can create many channels to a single file。